# Excel INDEX, CHOOSE, MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am having difficulty correcting my formula.

I am trying to work out someone's D.O.B and depending on their age apply a % fee to their account, I also have an option to give a 50% reduction.

The Index/Table I am working with is:
[Shows Age Range, Initial Fee % and Reduced if Applicable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAVLV.png)

- The table starts on S3 and Finishes on U9
- Column R (The Under 65, 65-74, etc) is the age ranges I want to use, but I am not sure if there's a way to grab the ranges from that (Is there a way to incorporate a wildcard search feature or some sort?)
- Client's age is displayed in F3
- Cell J1 is cell linked to a tick box that displays TRUE/FALSE to give output for the 50% reduction

My formula I have is:

```
=INDEX(T3:U9,CHOOSE(MATCH(F3,S3:S9),2,3,4,5,6,7,8),MATCH(J1,T2:U2,0))
```

The issue I am encountering is that when I determine the values, they are always off by 1 cell (i.e. if a client is 76, it will display 5% as opposed to 6%. I tried to adjust this by starting at Value2, but didn't take into account if the client is under 65 and I am not sure how to adjust for this

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You tag `excel-2007`. If you are on latest version of excel then use `XLOOKUP()`.

Comment: @Harun24hr, I should've tagged excel-2016 as that's what I have access to - would've been handy to have access to XLOOKUP

Comment: INDEX() with MATCH() will usually work instead of XLOOKUP()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly , you need the correct persentage to the age.
You can use VLOOKUP for this. In my example:

```
=VLOOKUP(B11;B2:C8;2;TRUE) -> 2,5%
```

The ages have to be sorted asc, the last parameter from VLOOKUP() have to be TRUE. (Maybe you have to change the semicolon to comma in your system)

[image]